# How to avoid queries got cancelled when you have a custom hook with AbortSignal with React-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

How to avoid queries got cancelled when you have a custom hook with AbortSignal with React-query

We used a custom hook to lunch the data fetch
which triggers the consumer component re-rendering (mounted<->un-mounted) many times during a data fetch session.
And we got the first query cancelled  when we pass down an abort signal on this React query function.

Any best practice to avoid this pattern would be appreciated?

```
const SampleQueryPage = ({showPromotion}) => {

    const [ productId] = ["12345"];

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.warn(`SampleQueryPage.tsx mounted`)
        return () => {
            console.warn(`SampleQueryPage.tsx un-mounted`)
        }
    });

    const getProduct = useGetProduct(showPromotion, productId, urlParamHash)

    return (
        <Button
            onClick={() => {
                getProduct.fetchNextPage();
            }}
        >
            load data
        </Button>
    );
};
```

```
function useGetProduct(
    showPromotion,productId, urlParamHash
) {
    const showPromotionQuery = useInfiniteQuery(
        ['show-first', productId, urlParamHash], 
        ()=>getProductWithPromotions({productId, params:urlParamHash}),
        getNextPageParam: ...
    )
    const notShowPromotionQuery = useInfiniteQuery(
        ['productId', productId, urlParamHash], 
        ()=>getProduct({productId, params:urlParamHash}),
        getNextPageParam: ...
    )

    return showPromotion ? showPromotionQuery : notShowPromotionQuery;
    
}

export default useGetProduct;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code where you are consuming the abortSignal, but, aborting a request is what the signal does.

So if you don't want requests to be cancelled - don't consume the abortSignal. Then, queries will continue to run in the background even though there are no active consumers anymore, and will be put into the cache for later use.